# array index 0 set to a variable and then returns nil value, Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

With the puts command below I output the contents of my variable `new_array` and its contents at index 0, which I also have stored in a variable called `first element`. I then output the class of `first_element` and I get a `nil` class returned. Can someone explain why this is? Also, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

```
new_array = []

first_element = new_array[0]

array = ["1", "2"]

array.each do |x|
    new_array << x.to_i
end

puts new_array[0]
puts first_element.class
```

output

```
$ruby testing_2.rb
1
NilClass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `new_array` is initialized, it's initialized as an empty array. That means it has zero elements. If you try to access an index, you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist. In Ruby, this is referred to as nil.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying. I moved it below the each method and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the first value of a blank array, which does not exist, so it becomes `nil`. `NilClass` is simply the class name for a `nil` object.

To make it not `nil`, you need to put something in your `new_array`, such as `["foo","bar",3.14]`. Then, the `first_element` will be `"foo"`, which is the `String` class.